# Sessão no php se perde após mudar de pagina

Tags: php, apache, session

Estou tendo sérios problemas preciso faze um deploy de um script em php que eu fiz em um servidor centos que eu instalei.
Aparentemente tudo ok. Ate a hora de fazer o login.

ele loga mas volta para tela d login e não gera erros.

dei um vardump na sessão logo apos ela ser criada e esta ok só que se eu recarrego atela ou passo para outra ele perde esta sessão.
alguém poderia me ajudar a achar o erro na configuração do php no linux ??

meu php.ini

https://pastebin.com/H9RSQdmk

parece que ele esta gerando uma sessão nova ( arquivo ) a cada vez q eu dou reload na pagina.

Comment: Pergunta besta, mas no passo seguinte a página tem session_start()? Ela é imprescindível em qualquer página que utilize sessão. Não apenas para criá-la.

Comment: cara nao é problema do php e sim do servidor centos que eu instalei esse sistema que eu fiz funciona ate na locaweb :(

Comment: Cara, por via das dúvidas, libera os erros do servidor. Se for algo relacionado ao path da sessão, poderemos saber por lá.

Comment: o problema he q nao he pau no patch eu achei que fosse e troquei a pasta e ele esta sendo gerado normalmente se eu editar os arquivos ele mostra a sessão gerada. pelo que eu vi cada vez q vc abre uma pagina em php ele ta gerando uma sessão nova do 0. Eu to instalando o centos 7 ao invez do 6 pra v c eu consigo fazer funcionar

Comment: você já chegou a testar e diferentes navegadores ? no Google Chrome mesmo algumas extensões podem zerar a sessão do php constantemente como o safe torrent scanner por exemplo